# How to convey the emotion "I am happy"

Tags: значения, выбор-слова

There are certain words and phrases that mean satisfied, happy, or otherwise contented

> я рад
>
> я доволен
>
> я удовлетворен

In english, "I am happy", that is "being happy"  is a state of mind and a state of being, an emotion, can be disconnected from a particular event or set of circumstances.

What word or phrase would closest replicate the meaning of the English word for the emotion of happiness and the phrase "I am happy" .

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's "я [счастлив](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2)" (derived from ["счастье"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5#Russian), happiness), and it's the first thing that Google Translate will suggest you as a translation of "I am happy" by the way.

Comment: It is not as simple as that, actually. Russian *счастлив* overlaps with English *happy* only partially, i.e. it only fits certain contexts but will be way off in others. See https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/i%27m+happy to get a rough idea. A phrase *I'm happy to take a bus* can hardly be translated *Я счастлив поехать автобусом*.

Comment: @tum_ very true, however question was specifically about emotion of happiness.

Comment: Yes, I realised this after I've sent the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Also, when you are just being very, very, very happy a Russian could say "я на седьмом небе от счастья".